# ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (637, 1162) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 637, 1162)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

i m getting the mentioned error. i want to load single image as input 
and train it across given masked image for image binary 
classification.

```
import tensorflow as tf

import os

import cv2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np



images = []

file_names = [os.path.join('../', f)
                      for f in os.listdir('../')
                      if f.endswith(".jpg")]

for f in file_names:
            images.append(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(f,1), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

img_mask = images[0];

retval,mask_img = cv2.threshold(img_mask, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

mask_img = mask_img/255

maskk = np.concatenate(mask_img)

x = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None, 637, 1162])

y = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, shape = [None])
```

## Flatten the input data

```
images_flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
```

## Fully connected layer

```
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat, 2, tf.nn.relu)
```

## Define a loss function

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = logits))
```

## Define an optimizer

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)
```

## Convert logits to label indexes

```
correct_pred = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
```

## Define an accuracy metric

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32)


tf.set_random_seed(1234)
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(201):

        print('EPOCH', i)
        _, accuracy_val = sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: 
        images[1], y: maskk})
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Loss: ", loss)
        print('DONE WITH EPOCH')
```

Comment: Can you show us where do you get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the batch size dimension, try `np.expand_dims(image, dim=0)`

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked. but now i am getting an error of label rank. i have masked image which i want to use as labels. mask image has two types of values 1 and 0. I want to train pixels of my input image on given mask image truth.  Now i am getting this error. "ValueError: Rank mismatch: Rank of labels (received 2) should equal rank of logits minus 1 (received 2)."  My session run is.  "sess.run([train_op, accuracy], feed_dict={x: np.expand_dims(images[1], axis=0), y: np.expand_dims(maskk, axis=1)})".